# Regular Expression Zero quantifier behaves differently on .NET and Mono

Tags: c#, .net, regex, mono

I am trying to use a regular expression in C# to break up a string into up to 3 distinct parts, Left, Middle, Right.
The expression pattern is built dynamically using input parameters to set the Left and Right quantifiers.
In most cases where the quantifier is one or higher it works fine, however if the left and right quantifiers are set to zero, the behavior is different on .NET 3.5 on Windows and on Mono 2.01.9 on Suse.

For example, using the following match string to test the string "1412":

```
^(?<left>.{0})(?<mid>.+)(?<right>.{0})
```

On Windows (.NET 3.5) the match groups show, as expected:

```
left:
mid:   1412
right:
```

On Suse (Mono 2.10.9) the match groups are:

```
left:   141
mid:    2
right:
```

Playing around with this, if I change the left and right quantifiers in the pattern to be non-greedy, I get the same (expected) result on both platforms:

```
^(?<left>.{0}?)(?<mid>.+)(?<right>.{0}?)

left:
mid:    1412
right:
```

While this seems to solve the problem, this section of code is of critical importance to our application so I would like to understand why the behavior is different in the original pattern.

Comment: Is `-` in `-^(?<left>.{0})(?<mid>.+)(?<right>.{0})` a typo?

Comment: Yes the pattern should be `^(?<left>.{0})(?<mid>.+)(?<right>.{0})`
Example Edited

Comment: What happens if you use `{0,0}`?

Comment: The same result as using a greedy {0}. 
.NET behaves as expected, but Mono places the last character in mid.

    `^(?<left>.{0,0})(?<mid>.+)(?<right>.{0,0})

    left: 141

    mid: 2

    right:`

Comment: FWIW, I believe Mono 4.0 uses Microsoft's .NET Regex implementation so they should behave EXACTLY the same.

Answer (score 0):

There are lazy and greedy quantifiers in the regex, and as per [Mastering Regular Expressions](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596528124) (taken from [here](http://www.moserware.com/2009/03/how-net-regular-expressions-really-work.html)),

> In situations where the decision is between “make an attempt” and
>   “skip an attempt,” as with items governed by quantifiers, the engine
>   always chooses to first make the attempt for greedy quantifiers, and
>   to first skip the attempt for lazy (non-greedy) ones.

For some reason, [Mono regex](https://github.com/mosa/Mono-Class-Libraries/tree/master/mcs/class/System/System.Text.RegularExpressions) follows this path, and .NET Framework uses the logic set by the regular expression by applying appropriate behavior.